# When I try to use HTML with `JOptionPane`, HTML tags are printed instead of HTML formatting

Tags: java, html, swing, joptionpane

For some weird reason when I try to use HTML with `JOptionPane`, HTML tags are printed instead of HTML formatting.

```
String msg = "Please fix <HTML><BODY BGCOLOR=#FFCCCC>this</BODY></HTML>";
JLabel message = new JLabel(msg);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyApp.this, message, "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

and the output is:

```
Please fix <HTML><BODY BGCOLOR=#FFCCCC>this</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The entire string needs to be enclosed within the HTML tags. For example:

```
button = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
```

For more information, see [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Answer (score 13):

Also worth noting: it seems that having a newline in your string triggers `JOptionPane` to *not* render the string as HTML, whereas e.g. `JLabel` *does* allow newlines in the HTML.

Comment: In other words, replace the \n with the <br> within the html tags.

Answer (score 6):

Enclose your entire string within html tags.

Answer (score 5):

The `<HTML>` and `</HTML>` tag specify that the input is in HTML. If you want to use HTML in Swing components, they have to either not be HTML, or be entirely in HTML. You can change the background of text by using the `<FONT>` tag, It might also be neater to enclose your text in `<P>` tags, but that's more a question of taste.

Try using

```
String msg = "<HTML><BODY><P>Please fix <FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFCCCC"> this</FONT></P></BODY></HTML>";
```