# formatting number JOptionPane

Tags: java, html

Good day, i'm facing the following problem. i'm generating a random number which i need to display all along some text on a `JOptionPane`. if i were to use a `JLabel`, i could have just added the `JLabel` to the `JOptionPane` straight forward. but i don't wanna make use of it. and i'm using the html tags, rather.

My question is the following, how will i get %d to get the number that i'm generating to be displayed?

with programming languages like java, i can print by doing:

```
System.out.printf("%d", +number);

System.out.printf(%d +number);
```

How will i go about with html, from the bellow code?

```
int number = 20140000+ generator.nextInt(999);

String msg = "<html><h3><b>You have been successfully registered into MYCARE.<br><br>Your Patient ID is: %d. Please use it to login.</br></br></b></h3></html>" +number;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "INFORMATION", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you just concatenate number and string. Try `String.format()`:

```
String msg = String.format("<html><h3><b>You have been successfully registered into MYCARE.<br><br>Your Patient ID is: %d. Please use it to login.</br></br></b></h3></html>", number);
```

Comment: what am I missing in here this time .  It's not getting displayed as I formatted it on my JOptionPane.                           String msg = String.format("<html><h3>Ache not found.<br>Please, type in a body part name,such as: </br><br>eyes, ears, skin ...</br></b></h3></html>");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

Comment: `String.fromat()` replace %d or %s with argument that you pass after your string in your example it's number. In this example you have not any arguments and any %s for example, so nothing to formatting.

Comment: i'm using this  String msg = "<html><h3>Ache not found.<br>Please, type in a body part name,such as: </br><br>eyes, ears, skin ...</br></b></h3></html>";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                but it's not displaying this format, rather it's just a plain_text

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068742/when-i-try-to-use-html-with-joptionpane-html-tags-are-printed-instead-of-html maybe it would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

The normal System.out.printf() method works like this:

```
int number = 5;
System.out.printf("%s %d", "aString", number);  //output: "aString 5"
```

What you want, is to use this in a String. You can use String.format() to put values into a String:
Example:

```
String s = String.format("<html><h3><b>You have been successfully registered into MYCARE.<br><br>Your Patient ID is: %d. Please use it to login.</br></br></b></h3></html>",number;);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.