# How do I get html formatting to show within a JOptionPane?

Tags: html, joptionpane

I don't see why this is not working.

```
String address = "somebody@abc.com";
String htmlText = "<html><br><font color='red'>" + address + "</font></html>";

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component, "My App v0 \n\n" + 
                            "Send questions or comments to: " + htmlText, 
                            "Questions", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

What shows up in the message box is the html tags surrounding the address...exactly like in the htmlText assignment.

## I expect to only see the address with the html formatting applied.

I put all of the html and the address in the string and still get the same results:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(toolbar, "WFM Network Calculator Version 0.6 
   \n\n" + "Send questions or comments to: <html><br><font 
   color='red'>Someone@abc.com</font></html>", 
   "About",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Probably the issue explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068742/when-i-try-to-use-html-with-joptionpane-html-tags-are-printed-instead-of-html)

Comment: Did you also try to set the starting `<html>`-tag at the beginning of the string as explained in the linked question?